# How to work with real email in laravel 5.4, not mailtrap.io or something like this

Tags: laravel

I am searching from fey days about using real email in laravel. Real email means If a user register then the registration confirmation link should go to his email. This could be any email, like gmail, yahoo etc. Difference user will have difference email. I want to send registration confirmation link to their own email. Not a specific email. Can anyone please help me. I have searched a lot about it, but maybe I wasn't on right track.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Laravel docs for Mail

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#introduction

You will need to set your mail driver and other details in the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Comment: I have worked with it. Now I want to know how i can send email to users individual email. Not a specific email. `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`. I have used this. By this I can send email to mail trap account. My question is how i can send email to users individual email

Comment: Are you using the user's email address (i.e. $user->email)?

Comment: mailtrap is designed to catch all email (no matter what address is used) during development.  Check to the To: address on an email message in mailtrap.  If the To: address is correct, once you swap from mailtrap to a real email server, your emails will be send to the user's individual email mailbox

Comment: Yes I want to use user email. That's means I want to send registration confirmation link to the register user's email. For that how should I configure my .env file

Comment: Do you have a mail server?

Comment: If I swap to real email server then what change I have to do in my code. Cap you please say me details . Please. Yes I have mall server

Comment: All you need to do is to update the settings in the .env file.  The driver is still smtp, but you will need to add your domain name to the MAIL_HOST setting (replace smtp.mailtrap.io with your server host name and domain.  Update the username and password too.  You shouldn't need to change your code at all, just the environment settings in the .env file.